# How to re-direct STDOUT and STDERR into file and on screen while running perl test case

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testcase, test-more

I have written simple Perl test case
Example:

```
use Test::More;
is(2 + 4, 5, "Addition check");
```

output on the screen:

```
Failed test 'Addition check'
at t/simpel_perl_test.t line 2.
got: '6'
expected: '5'
```

Now I want to print a message in log file and on screen ?

I am not able use existing Perl modules `IO::Tee` in `<test case name>.t` to achieve my requirement.

Could you tell how could I write a message on screen and in a log file in Perl test case?

#### Command used:

```
prove -r --timer t/simpel_perl_test.t :: -d
```

Comment: Please add a sample of how you call your tests if you get a logfile and screen output. Maybe a simple `prove mytest.t 2>&1 | tee logfile.log` would solve your problem?

Comment: I understand your suggestion but the test case is executing through wrapper script.

Comment: i got Error message as "Ambiguous output redirect"

Answer (score 1):

The [`IO::Capture`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Capture) modules were written exactly for doing this **during test execution**. Start by reading [`IO::Capture::Overview`](https://metacpan.org/source/REYNOLDS/IO-Capture-0.05/lib/IO/Capture/Overview.pod). However you appear to want the test harnesses output to be sent to a file instead. Maybe you want to provide a formatter argument to `prove` that could write to a file. You could follow up the `prove` invocation with `cat`ing the file. Try the [TAP::Formatter::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/TAP::Formatter::File) module as your argument, though I can't easily see how the file gets named.

Wouldn't it just be best to use the `tee` command for this?

```
$ prove -r --timer simple_perl_test.t :: -d |tee simple_perl_test.txt
[02:08:12] simple_perl_test.t .. ok       24 ms ( 0.00 usr  0.00 sys +  0.02 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.02 CPU)
[02:08:12]
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.02 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.05 CPU)
Result: PASS
$ cat simple_perl_test.txt 
[02:08:12] simple_perl_test.t .. ok       24 ms ( 0.00 usr  0.00 sys +  0.02 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.02 CPU)
[02:08:12]
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.02 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.05 CPU)
Result: PASS
$
```

Comment: The IO::Capture module function is not capturing "is", "ok" , "diag" , "pass" test etc display message into either IO::Capture::StrErr or STDOUT or @RESUTS.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to understand. I have a query about test failed case. if "is" test failed then I could not see on screen message in simple_perl_test.txt file. Please tell me how capture failed and passed debug message into simple_perl_test.txt file.